# Executing all datatable rows when using rich:dataScroller

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, datascroller

I'm facing this problem when using Richfaces 4.x... what I have is a datatable in edit mode so where the user can insert data using textboxes or radioButtons. The table needs to have a maximun of 10 rows per page reason why I also use a **rich:Datascroller** to paginate.

Suppose I'm on page 1 and there are validation errors on page 3, when the user clicks the save button JSF sends the entire table. However, since only the values of page 1 are visible it bypasses validations for rows on page 3. Any ideas how can I avoid this problem?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? You want it to validate page 3 even when you are on page 1, is it?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, since in page 3 I have some required=true fields.

Comment: What render type do you have on the `Save` or `Update` button? I think If you use `render="@table"`, it would validate your page 3 fields as well.

Comment: No, it's not. I'm executing the whole table, especified by the table id. Don't think it would be different to use @table or is it?

Comment: Ohh..Yes you are right. It wouldn't make any difference! hmm..